# Delete rows from a table with a view in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-delete, sql-view

Is it possible to delete rows from a table with a view?

If yes, how can we do that in PostgreSQL?
If no, what is the alternative?

Comment: This is unclear and really incomplete. What do you want? What records? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Are you looking for updatable views? If so, *did you read the manual first*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning from version 9.3, views are uptatable in PostgreSql.
Refer to documentation : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html (look for "updatable views") to know conditions that must be meet by the view to be "updatable".
A very simple example:

```
create table tbl1  
( rollnumber int,  
name varchar) ;

insert into tbl1 values(1,'abc');  
insert into tbl1 values(2,'def');  
insert into tbl1 values(3,'ghi');

create view view1 as select * from tbl1;


delete from view1 where rollnumber=2;
```

working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22c2f/1

Answer (score 0):

You can delete rows from a table with a view.

For example, you create `person` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  first_name VARCHAR(20),
  last_name VARCHAR(20),
  age INTEGER
);
```

Then, you insert 4 rows into `person` table as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', 27), 
       (2, 'David', 'Miller', 32), 
       (3, 'Robert', 'Brown', 18), 
       (4, 'Mark', 'Davis', 40);
```

Then, calling `person` gets the result as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | first_name | last_name | age
----+------------+-----------+-----
  1 | John       | Smith     |  27
  2 | David      | Miller    |  32
  3 | Robert     | Brown     |  18
  4 | Mark       | Davis     |  40
(4 rows)
```

Then, you create `my_v` view as shown below:

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_v AS
  SELECT first_name, age FROM person;
```

Now, you can delete 2 rows from `person` table with `my_v` as shown below. *`id` and `last_name` are not usable:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_v WHERE age = 32 OR age = 40;
```

Then, 2 rows are deleted from `person` table as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | first_name | last_name | age
----+------------+-----------+-----
  1 | John       | Smith     |  27
  3 | Robert     | Brown     |  18
(2 rows)
```